# how to get files running on a virtual machine

Tags: linux, vmware

My hostmachine is Windows, and install Ubuntu on a virtual machine. I developed some program on Ubuntu. Suppose I want to transfer these files to a folder in Windows. How to find and get these files, which logically are stored in the virtual machine.

Comment: what kind of VM?  Wmvare?

Comment: yes, its Vmware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use usb flash disk to transfer files between host and virtual machine (Vmware and VirtualBox do support usb).

Or

If you set up network in ubuntu, you could use samba for file sharing between OSes ([Samba setup described here](http://www.debuntu.org/guest-file-sharing-with-samba)). Then in windows open an explorer window, type **\\ubuntu.ip**

Answer (score 0):

Just install vmware tools in the VM, then you can copy them to a mounted host-filesystem, if you have enabled it (in settings).

However, it also lets you drag & drop (typically) from the file manager under Linux to Windows and vice versa, which is nice.